# generate primary key using date and time

Tags: php, mysql

i try to generate a primary key using `date` and `time` with php code.

but when i save the id change to `2147483647`.

my code to get date and time is.

```
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));
```

then i print it to input form with `readonly`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="idpost" name="idpost" value="<?php echo $dt->format('dmHis'); ?>" form="add_post" readonly>
```

Comment: The id type is integer or big int?

Comment: im using `int(12)` for it

Comment: And you do realize that the date format can have 0 in front, which will be ignored for type int?

Comment: hmm, i dont know...
so, what i have to do?

Comment: Don't use `date`/`time` for this purpose.  Just use an auto-incremented column and have a separate column for the creation date time -- as a `datetime` column.

Comment: You can try the answer below, or you can use varchar type as primary key or you can use unix timestamp, or create your own sequence in mysql (I am not sure if mysql can create sequence.)

Comment: @frz3993 thanks, i try varchar, its working with 0 in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` column is probably of type `INT` and `SIGNED` (default). This has a [maximum value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) of `2147483647`. With that date format, you're getting larger numbers (e.g. `3112133015`).

If you want to use numbers that large either use a `BIGINT` column, which has a maximum value of `9223372036854775807` or use an `UNSIGNED` `INT` so that the maximum value becomes `4294967295`.

Comment: what happen if theres 0 in front?

Comment: That will probably be cut off, but you can also use `j` instead of `d` in your date format.

Comment: what is `j` mean ?

Comment: See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php): `j` means the current day of month (just like `d`) *without* leading 0.

Answer (score 0):

its seems like its giving you timestamp  convert that to a readable date/time php time

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 2147483647);
```